# Program Files (x86) redirected? win 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems

I'm wondering if `c:\Program Files (x86)\` is redirected somewhere else under win2008 Server R2.

The thing is, a service is supposed to add/change fields in the settings file stored in `Program Files (x86)`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Please clarify your question.
Since Windows Server 2008 R2 is a x64 bit operating system, it has by default 2x Program Files folders. One is "Program Files" and is used for 64 bit software, and the other is Program Files (x86) for the 32 bit software.

Comment: I'm asking if service is installed in (x86) folder and tries to save/update it's settings stored under (x86). will its read/write requests be redirected somewhere else?

Comment: It is possible its settings to be stored in another folder. For example  many of the programs store its settings and confs on a per user basis for example: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\[app_name]` 
The folder AppData is hidden by default and you have to enable the Show Hidden Folders from Folder Options

Comment: @Spirit If you would be so kind as to post your answer *as an answer* instead of as a comment, I would be delighted to upvote it, and I suspect that AlexD would be happy to accept it too.

Comment: Just posted my comment as an answer.. I hope the answer helps. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the program's settings are stored in another folder. 
Many of the programs store its settings and confs on a per user basis for example:

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming[app_name]

The folder **AppData** is hidden by default and you have to enable the **Show Hidden Folders** from Folder Options

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not redirected at the file system level. However, UAC will "protect" directories that normal users do not have write access to and map those writes into the user's profile (I don't remember the exact location). The same will happen for other key locations (such as the Windows directory where many programs used to same ini files).